# Find the percentage of area leaves covering the frame in the image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have to extract the area of the leaves covering the frame causing occlusion to the camera.

I have tried canny threshold and then find `cv2.contours` and drawn with it with `thickness=cv2.FILLED`.

The original image:

[image: orignal image having leaf in centre frame]

and the output image:

[image: image ouput with edges and contours drawn]

I want to have ouput where only leave edges are only visible in black mask and other background in filled white mask.

```py
window_name = 'Edge Map'
title_trackbar = 'Min Threshold:'
kernel_size = 3

def CannyThreshold(imagepath):
    print(imagepath)
    image = cv2.imread(imagepath)
    #b,g,r = cv2.split(image)
    #leaf = image[...,0]
    #print(leaf.shape)
    img2 = image.copy()
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.blur(img_gray, (3,3))
    #img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 5), 0)
    
    detected_edges = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 30,150, kernel_size)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(detected_edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    #filtered_contours = [contour for contour in contours if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 100]
    
    mask = np.zeros(img2.shape, np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, (255,255,255),thickness=cv2.FILLED)
    
    
    cv2.imshow('thres',mask)
    cv2.imshow('img', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: canny is wrong. it doesn't help in your assignment. nor will contours help. a mask will help.

Comment: Can't you threshold on green, then get the largest contour and get the area of the largest contour.

Comment: why contours at all? just count the green pixels. unless the task really is to assess whether one leaf covers the view onto all the other leaves (and the dirt).

Answer (score -3):

Based on your description and code, it seems like you want to extract the edges of the leaves as a black mask and fill the background with white. Here's an updated version of your code that should achieve that:

```
def extract_leaf_edges(imagepath):
    image = cv2.imread(imagepath)
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.blur(img_gray, (3, 3))

    edges = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 30, 150)

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, (255, 255, 255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)

    mask_gray = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    mask_gray_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask_gray)

    result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask_gray_inv)

    cv2.imshow('Leaf Edges', result)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

image_path = 'path_to_your_image.jpg'
extract_leaf_edges(image_path)
```

In this updated code, I modified the draw Contours function to fill the contours with white color (255, 255, 255) on a black mask. Then, I converted the mask to grayscale and applied bitwise operations to extract the leaf edges and display them on a black background.

Make sure to replace 'path_to_your_image.jpg' with the actual path to your input image.

Comment: the only relevant changes are three additions: (1) `cvtColor` to turn the mask from BGR to gray (it's black and white already), (2) a `bitwise_not` to invert the mask, (3) a `bitwise_and` of that onto `image`. -- here's the diff, after modifying both codes while preserving semantics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/czzMY.png -- this didn't calculate any are, it merely produced an illustration